# Android: How to capture key events from Bluetooth headphones?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, onkeydown

I am trying to capture KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE key events from Bluetooth headphones. I tried to override onKeyDown in the MainActivity to get the keyCode, but I only got events from the phone, never from the Bluetooth headphones. I found some similar questions, but couldn't find any solution. Thanks!

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    Timber.d("$keyCode")
    when (keyCode) {
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE -> {               
            Timber.d("Received")
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is facing the same issue, this is what worked for me now:

```
fun configureMediaSession(){
s_mediaSession = MediaSession(this, "MyMediaSession")
    s_mediaSession.setCallback(object : MediaSession.Callback() {
        override fun onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent: Intent): Boolean {
            val ke: KeyEvent? = mediaButtonIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT)
            if (ke != null && ke.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Calling my method
                return true
            }
            return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent)
        }
    })
}
```

It would be great if anyone can share a better solution.

Comment: does not work for me. Can you share the whole activity code?